# undefined reference to 'main' no read source file

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I've got a strange issue when I try to compile my code on my laptop.
It gives me this error: `undefined reference to 'main'` because apparently it cannot see my source files and then the objects either.

However, the same makefile and code work perfectly on my office machine.

here's the makefile. any hints?

thanks a lot for helping me in advance

```
ROOT = $(addprefix $(PWD), /)
BUILDS_DIR = $(addprefix $(ROOT), builds/)
SRCS_DIR   = $(addprefix $(ROOT), src/)
INCS_DIR   = $(addprefix $(ROOT), src/)
OBJS_DIR   = $(addprefix $(SRCS_DIR), objects/)
LIBS_DIR   = ./

SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRCS_DIR)*.c)
OBJS = $(SRCS:$(SRCS_DIR)%.c=$(OBJS_DIR)%.o)

TARGET = INTERP

EXES = $(addprefix $(BUILDS_DIR), $(TARGET))

CC       = gcc
CFLAGS   = -Wall -O3 -MD -DTRILIBRARY
INCLUDES = -I$(INCS_DIR)
CL       = gcc
LFLAGS   = 
LIBS     = -L$(LIBS_DIR) -lm
RM       = rm -f

.PHONY: all $(TARGET) distclean clean

default: clean $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    @echo -e "\n\n\t\t*** Compiled $(TARGET) successfully! ***\n" ;
    $(CL) $(LFLAGS) -o $(BUILDS_DIR)$@ \
        $(OBJS) \
        $(LIBS)
    @echo -e "\n\n\t\t*** Linking $(TARGET) completed! ***\n"

$(OBJS): $(OBJS_DIR)%.o : $(SRCS_DIR)%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) \
        -c $<\
        -o $@

distclean: clean
    $(RM) $(EXES)
    @echo -e "\n\n\t\t*** Purge $(TARGET) completed! ***\n"

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS_DIR)*.o \
        $(SRCS_DIR)*~
    @echo -e "\n\n\t\t*** Cleanup $(TARGET) completed! ***\n"

depend: $(SRCS)
    makedepend $(INCLUDES) $^
```

Comment: Check the MACRO definitions validity first. It's most likely that the path is not valid in your laptop.

Comment: Can you include the filename that is supposed to include `main()`, and the output of `make INTERP` after running `make clean`?

Comment: Run `make --trace` assuming you have a recent GNU make. Or try [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) `-x` to understand what is going on.

Comment: @SouravGhosh which MACRO definitions do you mean?
@BillLynch `main()` is in a file named simply main.
@BasileStarynkevitch I have gcc 4.6 but `make --trace` does not work

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the GNU make version I'm using is 3.81

Comment: You  mean a file named main.c, or literally named "main"?